# How to fill users variable with data from GET request in React

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am making a GET call request to an API in order to fetch some data in my React component and save it to my `users` variable, but the data does not get saved, I get `undefined` when I console.log it. How can I set the response data from my GET call and save it in the `users` variable? Here is my attempt:

```
 const [users, setPosts] = React.useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => console.log(data));

    setPosts(users.data);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code you have posted, you aren't saving the data to users. Try this:

```
useEffect(() => {
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then(setPosts);
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should be do it:

```
const [users, setPosts] = React.useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setPosts(data););
  }, []);
```

That way you set your `users` as `data`

Also as a `hook rule` you should define your state as follow `const [users, setUsers] = useState()`